# How to mask a raster image with classified image class mask?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2

I have classified an image having a class by the name lights. It has value equal to zero. I select the mask by using

```
var lights_mask = classified_image.eq(0).selfMask(); //binary mask
```

Now I want to subtract the original image from this raster mask.
I have used both methods

```
var masked_image = image.updateMask(lights_mask);
//or
//var masked_image = image.subtract(lights_mask);
```

But it returns the original image with masked portion only. I want the mask portion to be removed and the rest of the multi-band image remains the same.

Simple put I want to clip a raster using a raster binary mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `.selfMask().mask()`.